# save unrelated model within controller in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

In my post controller,  I saved comment and it worked perfectly. 
Now I want to save a record in a summary table.  When I save the record, I systematically, get the error going to the else option. Do I need to do something more?  Thank you for your help.

```
if (isset($_POST['Comment'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Comment'];

            if ($model->save()) {


                $modelSummary = new SummaryComment;     -- Summary Table
                $modelSummary->summary_for = 1;         --  test value
                $modelSummary->post_id = 18;            -- test value  (existing post_id)

                if ($modelSummary->save()) {            -- Save Summary Table

                  $arr = array(array('c_id' => $model->id));
                  echo json_encode($arr);
                  return;
                } else {

                 echo "error";
                }

            }
```

Comment: need some more details. What is the library that you are using for models. From the post it looks like php-activerecord. Please confirm

Comment: You've posted the wrong code, if `$modelSummary->save()` returns something that evaluates to false, the problem is in that method.

Comment: @Guns , I'm using Yii framework.  I have a model called SummaryComment.

Comment: added some tags that will help you get the appropriate answer. It is important that you tag your question well in order to get an appropriate answer. You need to accept the edit

Comment: @guns thank you I accepted the edit

Comment: in else block vardump $model->getErrors(); to get error messages

Comment: @AndreyMischenko  how to use $model->getErrors(), simply typing it in the else does not get any message

Comment: Ok I found the response,  I got an error in saving the primary key